# no data are showing when I try to use the search function

Tags: php, mysql

I need som help to figure out why my search function doesn't work. I am a beginner in php, dont really have that much knowledge. I saw this code for a search function and tried to use it but it doesn't work.

```
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if(isset($_GET['go'])){
  if(preg_match("/^[  a-zA-Z]+/", $_POST['name'])){
  $name=$_POST['name'];

 include("config.php");

$stmt = $connect->prepare('SELECT id, title FROM news WHERE title LIKE '%" . $name . "%'');
$stmt->execute();


while($sa = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

?>
<p><?php echo $sa['title'];?><br/></p>

                <?
                }
                }
                }
                }
                ?>
```

This is the form:

```
<div id="search-form" class="pull-right">
                        <form method="post" action="search.php?go" id="searchform">
                            <input type="text" name="name" value="" required />
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="S&ouml;k"/>
                                            </form>
```

Comment: any error? 
have you tr to print the result return by query?

Comment: I dont really understand.. like I said. I am a beginner at this. Can you show me what you mean?

Comment: Refernce link from where you copy the code?

Comment: I do not have the website, but I haven't changed nothing

Comment: OK just just wait a moment i will be right back to you seraching on my machine

Comment: Replace the line $connect->prepare('SELECT * FROM news
    WHERE column LIKE '%".$name."%' ');

Comment: with what should I replace it? thx for the answer

Comment: replace the query line and let me know if works

Comment: I dont know really what to do.. replace it with what? It will not work

Comment: Follow here http://tutorial.world.edu/web-development/how-to-create-database-search-mysql-php-script/

Comment: Try if  fails let me know

Comment: Glad to help ;)